# Residuals of SARIMA follow Student's $t$ distribution - implications?

Tags: time-series, distributions, arima, residuals, t-distribution

I have fitted a SARIMA model to my time series. The diagnostics of the residuals are all good (ACF, PACF, ...), i.e. it seems they behave like white noise.

But when I plot the normal qq-plot, they seem to be asymmetrically distributed. I tried doing a Student's $t$ qq-plot and the errors seems to be corrected. My only problem is that now, I do not know how to interpret this result.

What does it mean for the residuals to follow a Student's $t$ distribution?

Comment: what is the context? what is the application? this could mean many different things depending on your problem

Answer (score 2):

If the residuals appear to be asymmetric judging by the normal Q-Q plot, it surprises me that they no longer appear asymmetric judging by the Student's $t$ Q-Q plot, because both the Normal and the Student's $t$ distributions are symmetric.

Aside of that, you can say you have fit your SARIMA model using quasi maximum likelihood (QML) rather than maximum likelihood (ML), as the realized error distribution does not match the assumed error distribution. Since both Normal and Student's $t$ distributions are in the same exponential family, the QML coefficient estimators are consistent. Just the standard errors should be adjusted to reflect the mismatch in distributions.

Comment: Please explain in greater detail. For example, if $1<v\leq 2$ then the second moment (standard deviation squared) of a Student's-$t$ is not defined. I would in that case use jackknife of 1/2 of the number of samples 1000 times to establish confidence intervals, which would not depend on a distribution assumption at all, what would you do?

Comment: I don't see how your comment is related to my answer. It might be an interesting question in itself, though, I do not argue about that. Regarding degrees of freedom: heavy tails may be problematic, and I am not sure how well QML works in case of Student-$t$ with $t<2$. One should check the assumptions for QML to work to be sure.

Comment: A few more notes. First, jackknife, bootstrap and related techniques cannot be straightforwardly applied to time series where the time dimension plays a role; and especially to (S)ARIMA models where model parameters are highly nonlinear functions of errors. Second,  jackknife (unlike boostrap subsampling) is done once (not 1000 times) for a fixed sample. Third, variance (squared standard deviation) is second *central* moment.

Comment: OK, central moment. Easy to show linear case, SARIMA residuals, if they are Student's-$t$ do not care what they came from, they are what they are. What I have done is to point the way to back calculating them, by using Monte Carlo simulation. Jackknife after 1000 resamplings of 206 objects from a collection of 412 is likely enough, doing it once would be impossible for the $1.163427960939212\times 10^{511}$ resamplings, what what I was getting at.

Comment: The default model selection criterion in Mathematica 10.3 for their TimeSeriesModelFit that takes SARMA (seasonal autoregressive moving-average model family) is AIC. I do not know what was used for the question above. Maximum likelihood does not appear to DO anything differently than minimizing SSR (sum squared residuals), which is OLS. Maybe there is some subtle difference that you could explain to me. In practice, to use AIC for model selection may require more random searching and lots of it for non-normal conditions. Consider using other criteria for model selection and then compare.

Comment: @Carl, The following is incorrect except for one special case -- normality: *Maximum likelihood does not appear to DO anything differently than minimizing SSR (sum squared residuals), which is OLS.* You could try a slightly advanced econometrics textbook (introductory one could probably also do) for an introduction to the maximum likelihood principle and estimation. You would see that the principle has quite different ideas in its background as compared to OLS.

Comment: I agree there may be subtle differences. However, none that matters from my point of view. What maximum likelihood is not is an inverse method. It pays attention to goodness-of-fit, not to parametric goals of fitting. Perhaps I am wrong about that, but I have certainly never seen it used to minimize error propagation of a combination of fitting parameters. Also, the normal residual assumption is naive in the extreme.

Comment: BTW, the one case where OLS and maximum likelihood can agree is linear regression iff the residuals are normally distributed, which is what I used for the example above, now granted since the residuals are not normally distributed, then the assumption for maximum likelihood is violated, and for OLS as well. Can we chat privately?

Comment: Why don't you ask a separate question and then everyone could join in.

Comment: Which question did you have in mind, I have about 10 of them? BTW, (+1) for your *sagesse*.

Comment: @Carl, this was 3.5 years ago, I cannot remember what I had in mind back then any longer.

Comment: Well, then I shall stop wondering. One of life's little mysteries, I guess.

Comment: @Carl, well put!

Answer (score 2):

### What does it mean for the residuals to follow a Student's t distribution?

The meaning depends on the degrees of freedom, $v$, of the Student's-*t* Distribution. For background information the Wikipedia entries on the Cauchy, Student's-$t$, and normal distributions are useful reading. I have not seen anything theoretically quantify the regression errors for the Student's-$t$ distribution from ordinary least squares (OLS) regression. For maximum likelihood iff degrees of freedom > 2 one can use [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/specify-regarima-model-innovation-distribution.html?searchHighlight=student%20distribution%20arima&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#btybox8-1), also see [ref. Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229407/what-are-the-effects-of-students-t-residuals-upon-maximum-likelihood-estimati/229421#229421). It is easy enough to show what the effects are using simulations.

For 1 degree of freedom, the Student's-*t* becomes a Cauchy distribution and OLS regression is not useful, because the mean of a Cauchy distribution is undefined (therefore unstable when calculated). See the first image, Monte Carlo simulation of 10000 Cauchy residuals for sequential equidistant x-axis points, below with regression equation $y=3.50054 x-19394.7$ where the truth is $y=x$ [image: Monte Carlo simulation of 10000 Cauchy residuals for sequential equidistant x-axis points]

When the degrees of freedom are greater than 1 up to and including 2, the mean is defined but the standard deviation (second moment) is not defined, and then the OLS regression is more accurate but not exact, see next image with $v=2$, and regression equation $1.04074 x-337.02$. [[image: <span class=]$v=2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KQdd.png)

As $v$ increases the regression accuracy does as well. At $v>3$, the third moment, skewness is defined. For $v>4$ kurtosis is defined, and so on for higher moments and degrees of freedom.

To get some idea of what this means in practice, I made sequential models for increasing $v$ on the $x$-axis using two sets of random numbers, which coincidentally approach a slope of one and intercept of zero from opposite directions. First the intercepts:[image: Intercepts for increasing df]

Next the slopes:[image: slopes for increasing df]

As $v\to \infty$ the Student's-$t$ distribution becomes a normal distribution. Thank-you for a very interesting question that I was wondering about myself.

Comment: While a nice answer, I think it misses the point. The question is not what realizations of a Student-$t$ distributed random variable look like but rather what does that mean in the context of (residuals of) SARIMA models. But let the OP decide how relevant that is.

Comment: The model residuals are Student's-$t$, exactly. The question was what is the effect, and, this is the easiest way of showing it. How one obtains residuals from more complicated models, like SARIMA models is rather besides the point, and the analysis of raw residuals does not much care what they came from. I get your point, if you have a better answer, I would be delighted to see it.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. The point is not how to obtain residuals from a model. It is what effect the mismatch between assumed and realized distributions (for errors and residuals, respectively) have on maximum likelihood estimates and, consequently, inference and forecasts from the model. I posted an answer for that on May 22.

Comment: I want to understand your answer better, it would help if you explained your answer in greater detail. My answer, use Monte Carlo simulation on whatever the data and model are has the advantage of being simple, and intuitive.

Comment: My answer has two parts: one regarding asymmetry, another regarding MLE and QMLE. I suppose you are interested in the second part. It is nothing special, just an application of the idea/principle of QMLE introduced in White, Halbert. ["Maximum likelihood estimation of misspecified models."](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912526) *Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society* (1982): 1-25. (There is also a reference to a nice treatment in Wooldridge's textbook in [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185154/idea-and-intuition-behind-quasi-maximum-likelihood-estimation-qmle).)

Comment: Given all this, what in particular would you like me to elaborate on?

Comment: Please expand your answer to include references on MLE, QML and QMLE. Of particular interest to me, is how the imposition of an additional criterion on OLS, that of normality of residuals, can be generalized so as to remove that odious presumption. There is a chicken and egg problem with AIC, misspecification shows up as non-normality in the residuals, and models are compared assuming no misspecification, in which case there is no possible preference for any model. By relaxing this self-contradiction, you may indeed have a solution, just elaborate, please.

Comment: References are included just above. OLS plays no role in SARIMA models; maximum likelihood estimation is used instead. How is AIC related to all this? Nonnormality of residuals does not imply misspecification as long as the likelihood function is nonnormal. I am afraid this discussion is getting too far away from the original question. You may ask a separate question with reference to this one, though.

Comment: I suggest that for maximum likelihood the effect of low degrees of freedom of Student's-t residuals will be to render the fit a hit and miss affair by introducing local maxima. For example, one might need to use multiple starting random values and then choose the best result. This may also yield a best fit that has no relationship to Student's-t, for example, it may turn out to be a mixture distribution.

Comment: AIC is used for model selection for SARIMA in Mathematica code. See Details and Options in [TimeSeriesModelFit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html). What would you suggest using?

Comment: Consider posting a separate question.

Comment: Happy to oblige but what question do you have in mind? SARIMA and AIC use, OLS and maximum likelihood difference or both?

Comment: Carl, at this point I do not really have any questions in mind; but it appears to me you want to discuss a few things. Since comments are not for discussions, I suggest posting your questions as questions. That is all I meant.