Goodness of Fit for Comparing Multiple Fractional Logit Models
I'd like to use employ a fractional logit model where my dependent variable is bounded between 0 and 1 and I have two independent variables. For this type of model, I'm unsure, and hoping to get some feedback on how to properly choose whether to choose a single independent variable or use both, to properly optimize my model.
To start, I decided to first run my fractional logit model by regressing on just the intercept, then regressing on the intercept and variable1, followed by regressing on the intercept and variable2 and finally regressing on variable1 and variable2.
After running each model, I want to run some diagnostics in order to check the goodness of fit and choose the best model but I'm unsure how to go about this with a fractional model. For OLS, I'd just use AIC/BIC and residuals to choose. For this type of model should I use an Anova approach or cross validation? Any thoughts or feedback is much appreciated.

A fractional logit model is just a GLM with a binomial family, a logit link, and heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors. To gauge fit, you can use all the standard approaches used for GLMs. But what is your ultimate goal for this model? That will determine what best means.

Possible duplicate ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409437/how-does-one-compare-two-nested-quasibinomial-glms,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418832/why-the-absence-of-probability-distribution-for-using-quasi-likelihood
